# python pandas: replace a str value of column in another str column with a special character

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas

There is a dataframe like as following.

```
   id     num     text
   1      1.2     price is 1.2
   1      2.3     price is 1.2 or 2.3
   2      3     The total value is $3 and $130
   3      5     The apple value is 5dollar and $150
```

I want to replace the num in the text with character 'UNK'

and  the new dataframe is changed to:

```
   id     num     text
   1      1.2     price is UNK
   1      2.3     price is 1.2 or UNK
   2      3    The total value is UNK and 130
   3      5     The apple value is UNK dollar and $150
```

z
My current code is as following

```
df_dev['text'].str.replace(df_dev['num'], 'UNK')
```

and there is error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us using `regex` and `replace`

```
df.text.replace(regex=r'(?i)'+ df.num.astype(str),value="UNK")
0              price is UNK
1       price is 1.2 or UNK
2    The total value is UNK
Name: text, dtype: object

#df.text=df.text.replace(regex=r'(?i)'+ df.num.astype(str),value="UNK")
```

Update

```
(df.text+' ').replace(regex=r'(?i) '+ df.num.astype(str)+' ',value=" UNK ")
0                      price is UNK 
1               price is 1.2 or UNK 
2    The total value is UNK and 130 
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. How about this text  num: 3  text: price is 3 and 130. Since the 130 include 3, I just want to get the price is UNK and 130

Comment: hi @W-B thanks, how about my updated question, when the number is like $3

Answer (score 1):

The error is correct, you can't feed a series to a method which [expects a string or regular expression](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html).

Pandas string methods aren't vectorised, i.e. they involve Python-level loops under the hood, so a list comprehension may work well:

```
zipper = zip(df['text'], df['num'].astype(str))
df['text'] = [text.replace(num, 'UNK') for text, num in zipper]
```

Comment: I am not sure why but seems like it can be vectorised?

Comment: @W-B, By vectorised I mean NumPy vectorised :). In other words, all the Pandas `str` methods just have Python-level loops under the hood.

Comment: @W-B, By the way, congrats on getting to 100k :)

Comment: Thank you man :-) Without your guys' help, this would not have been possible